# Need to import data from "push alert" plugin to another

Tags: database, wordpress, plugins, notifications, onesignal

I have previously installed "Push alert" plugins in my site, but it's free account has limitation of 3000 subscribers, after which they dont send notifications to the subscribers, I need to purchase this plugin to send notifications to more than 3000 subscribers. Now I found "Onesignal" which allows to send notifications to 10000 subscribers free. now I want to install it. But my question is can I get data of my previously installed plugin and import those data in my new plugin? Is it possible?

Comment: Ask plugin author if they support migration.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should ask your question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where more people may know the answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.